# Execute python script with a variable from linux shell

Tags: python, terminal, argparse, execute

This might be an easy question but I don't know the name of what I'm trying to do, so I don't know how to search for it.

Basically when I'm in terminal (linux command line) and I type

```
$ python do_something.py stuff
```

I want to get the `stuff` to mean something for my script. So two questions:

1. How is this called?
2. How can I do it?

Comment: `stuff` is called an argument, and python has a module called argparse to deal with various ways of accepting command line arguments. The documentation and examples are here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is for the `do_something.py` script to `import sys` and access the "stuff" command-line argument as `sys.argv(1)`.  There are many fancier ways, of course.

Comment: and the fancier ways make use of `sys.argv[1:]` behind the scenes (e.g. `optparse`, `argparse`)

Comment: @hpaulj, sure, and they may well be worth the extra fancy when needed, but perhaps not in the OP's case (hard to say as the Q is very concise about that).

Answer (score 3):

**What you're asking for is called argument parsing.**

To do this the proper way, you should definitively use **[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)**.

It's a neat and yet very powerful library to make argument parsing more efficient. Plus, it makes your scripts manage arguments *the proper Linux way*, by default.

**Basic example:**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My argparse program')

parser.add_argument('--verbose',
    action='store_true',
    help='sets output to verbose' )

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.verbose:
    print("~ Verbose!")
else:
    print("~ Not so verbose")
```

**Then you can do cool stuff like:**

```
$ python3 myscript.py --verbose
~ Verbose!
```

And what's even cooler, it provides an automatic `--help` (or `-h`) argument:

```
$ python3 myscript.py --help
usage: myscript.py [-h] [--verbose]

My argparse program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --verbose   sets output to verbose
```

This is the kind of library that allows you to quite easily do complicated stuff like:

```
./myscript.py --password=no -c -o --keep_moving --name="Robert"
```

**[Here is a link to a nice tutorial](https://mkaz.com/2014/07/26/python-argparse-cookbook/)** from which the above example has been freely adapted.